# how can I use flutter_test from sdk and the package test? what version of test uses test_api 0.4.3?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to run some basic unit test for my flutter app.  But when I run pub get I get the following error after including **test: 1.20.0** in my pubspec:

```
dev_dependencies:
  dependency_validator: ^3.1.0 # run flutter pub run dependency_validator
  #integration_test:
  #  sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.20.0
```

so when I run `f pub get` I see:

````
    Because test >=1.20.0 depends on test_api 0.4.9 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.3, test >=1.20.0 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
    So, because myapp depends on both flutter_test from sdk and test ^1.20.0, version solving failed.
    pub get failed (1; So, because myapp depends on both flutter_test from sdk and test ^1.20.0, version solving failed.)```

What version of test uses test_api  0.4.3?
````

Comment: Its not safe but if it works you could try using dependency_overrides

Comment: Thanks @EnviroApps, but it turns out I can just use **import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';** instead of importing directly from the test package in my test file.  Of course I realized this about 3 seconds after posting my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can just use import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart'; instead of importing directly from the test package in my test file. So I don't need to include test: 1.20.0 in my pubspec.

Comment: that is actually the best answer.

Answer (score 15):

Try overriding [test_api](https://pub.dev/packages/test_api) to 0.4.18 in your pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  test_api: 0.4.18
```

or

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^3.0.0
```

You can probably remove this next time flutter updates.

Answer (score 2):

Add **test_api** in **dependency_overrides**

example:

```
dependency_overrides:
  test_api: ^0.4.17

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  bloc_test: ^9.1.0
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
```